# how to trim vector char array or string?

Tags: c++, string, boost, trim

I am following this code to trim

```
    std::string tcp_read(int listen_at_port=8001){

    using namespace std;
    using namespace boost::algorithm;
    std::vector<char> received_data(512); 
    tcp_read(received_data, listen_at_port);
    string str1(received_data.begin(),received_data.end());
    trim_right(str1);
    return str1;
}
```

I stepped throught the code, my received_data is generally = "add 8002 (here onwards buffer is filled with spaces till the [511th] position)"

now when I did trim_right I expected the str1 size to become 8, but its still 512 when its returning, why?

How do i get actually trim and change the size so that the string just accomodates till the last non space character

Comment: Are you sure the buffer is filled with spaces and not some other whitespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16752234/241631), your `vector` is filled with zeros, which are not considered *whitespace*, so `trim_right` doesn't strip those from the string. An easy fix to your problem is to not construct the string using the begin and end iterators of the vector, but use the `string( char const * )` constructor. This also eliminates the call to `boost::trim_right`.

```
std::string tcp_read(int listen_at_port=8001)
{
    using namespace std;

    std::vector<char> received_data(512); 
    tcp_read(received_data, listen_at_port);

    return string( received_data.data() );
    // or return string( &received_data[0] );
}
```

Comment: what is an alternative to .data() of a vector on vs2008 which doesnt support c11?

Comment: @user494461 The commented out line `return string( &received_data[0] );` works for C++03 compilers.

Answer (score 1):

`trim_right` only removes all trailing whitespaces. When you declare `received_data` it is initialized with all zeros. When you read data from the socket the data at the end of the buffer is [most certainly] not composed of spaces.

I suggest that when you call `tcp_read()` you return the number of bytes that were actually read from the socket and do `recieved_data.resize(byte_count);` instead of calling `trim_right`. Also if the data received over the socket can contain zeros you should probably be returning a `vector` instead of `string`.

[Kudos to [Praetorian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/241631/praetorian) for pointing out that it removes all *whitespaces*]

Comment: +1 `trim_right` not only removes spaces, but all trailing *whitespace*. So he could modify the initialization of the vector so that it does contain something that `trim_right` will remove. For instance `std::vector<char> received_data(512, '\n');`

Comment: @Praetorian didn't think about all whitespaces though

Answer (score 0):

That's silly, but in case whitespaces aren't really whitespaces:

```
string str1(received_data.begin(), 
    find(received_data.begin(), received_data.end(), received_data[511]) );
```

And if they are:

```
string str1(received_data.begin(), 
    find( 
        find(received_data.begin(), received_data.end(), ' ') + 1, 
        received_data.end()) );
```

But that's just some hacks, trim right should work just fine, there's probably something wrong with the received_data.

And yes, trimming the string wouldn't reallocate any memory anyway, so it might be ok to store it as it is.